# RemoteViews object always return null in accessibility service

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, accessibility, accessibilityservice

Hello programmers how are you. i have a little problem.
I'm using `Accessibility Service` to Read `Notification` Title, Text but the problem is `notification.bigContentView` and `notification.contentView` always return null. on the remoteViews object it always return null. i'm using Android Marshmallow and Nougat for testing this code. i think remotViews always return null above lollipop. if yes then how can i read this data in my `Accessibility Service`.
Code is here:

```
@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    Log.v("Tortuga","FML");
    if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED) {

            Log.v("Tortuga","Recieved event");
            Parcelable data = event.getParcelableData();

            if (data instanceof Notification&&data!=null) {
                Log.v("Tortuga","Recieved notification");
                Notification notification = (Notification) event.getParcelableData();
                RemoteViews views = notification.contentView;

                if (views==null){
                    views = notification.bigContentView;
                    secretClass = views.getClass();
                }else
                {
                    secretClass = views.getClass();
                }

                try {
                    Map<Integer, String> text = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

                    Field outerFields[] = secretClass.getDeclaredFields();
                    for (int i = 0; i < outerFields.length; i++) {
                        if (!outerFields[i].getName().equals("mActions")) continue;

                        outerFields[i].setAccessible(true);

                        ArrayList<Object> actions = (ArrayList<Object>) outerFields[i]
                                .get(views);
                        for (Object action : actions) {
                            Field innerFields[] = action.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

                            Object value = null;
                            Integer type = null;
                            Integer viewId = null;
                            for (Field field : innerFields) {
                                field.setAccessible(true);
                                if (field.getName().equals("value")) {
                                    value = field.get(action);
                                } else if (field.getName().equals("type")) {
                                    type = field.getInt(action);
                                } else if (field.getName().equals("viewId")) {
                                    viewId = field.getInt(action);
                                }
                            }

                            if (type == 9 || type == 10) {
                                text.put(viewId, value.toString());
                            }
                        }

                        System.out.println("title is: " + text.get(16908310));
                        System.out.println("info is: " + text.get(16909082));
                        System.out.println("text is: " + text.get(16908358));
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                String pkg=event.getPackageName().toString();
                startService(new Intent(this,Send_Notification.class));
                stopService(new Intent(this,Send_Notification.class));
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "null event", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Accessibility services don't get access to the actual view objects, so this will never work. The data is actually stored in the Accessibility event. A notification's text, from the Accessibility Service's point of view, is usually stored in the `event.getText()` property, of the appropriate notification type.